# Reference to object with std::async

Tags: c++

I have a small solution in visual studio 2012. The solution consists of two projects (Scanner and TestApp), Scanner is a dll and TestApp is a small application using the dll.
I would like a function in the dll to run in a thread and to report its result back via a queue to the TestApp.
To test this I wrote a minimal application, but depending on how I launch the thread I get different results and I would like to understand why.

The **Scanner.h** file looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

#include "version.h"
#include "threadsafe_queue.h"
#include "capture_data.h"
#include "process_data.h"


#ifdef SCANNER_EXPORTS  
#define SCANNER_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define SCANNER_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

class Scanner
{
public:
    static SCANNER_API void run();  
    static SCANNER_API void stop(); 
};
```

**Scanner.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Scanner.h"

std::vector<std::future<int>> my_futures;

void Scanner::run()
{
    CaptureData capture_data(1234);
    auto t = std::async(std::launch::async, &CaptureData::get_data, capture_data);
    my_futures.push_back(std::move(t));
}

void Scanner::stop()
{
    for(int n=0; n<my_futures.size(); n++) {
    auto e = std::move(my_futures.back());
    e.get();
    my_futures.pop_back();
    }
}
```

The class CaptureData is defined in capture_data.h and capture_data.cpp.

**capture_data.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include "iq_data.h"
#include "threadsafe_queue.h"

class CaptureData
{
public:
    CaptureData(double freq_start);
    void configure();
    void get_data();
private:
    double m_test;
};
```

**capture_data.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "capture_data.h"
#include "Scanner.h"

ThreadsafeQueue<int> g_queue_1;
SCANNER_API ThreadsafeQueue<int> g_queue_2;


CaptureData::CaptureData(double test) 
    : m_test(test) {}

void CaptureData::get_data() 
{
    cout << "1: " << m_test << std::endl;
    Sleep(5000);
    cout << "2: " << m_test << std::endl;   
    g_queue_2.push(3);
    cout << "Capture has now pushed data" << std::endl;
}
```

And finally the **TestApp.cpp**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include "Scanner.h"


SCANNER_API extern ThreadsafeQueue<int> g_queue_2;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Scanner scanner;
    scanner.run();
    cout << "TestApp waiting for data..." << std::endl;
    int data;
    g_queue_2.wait_and_pop(data);
    cout << "TestApp got data: " << data << std::endl;
    scanner.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

In Scanner.cpp I have tried to launch the thread in two different ways, the first way:

```
auto t = std::async(std::launch::async, &CaptureData::get_data, capture_data);
```

Second way is with a reference to the object "capture_data":

```
auto t = std::async(std::launch::async, &CaptureData::get_data, &capture_data);
```

The first way seems to work as I intended the application to work and I get the following printouts in my terminal:

```
TestApp waiting for data... 
1: 1234 
2: 1234 
Capture has now pushed data 
TestApp got data: 3 
Press any key to continue...
```

If I use the second way I get:

```
TestApp waiting for data... 
1: 6.95166e-310
2: 6.95166e-310 
Capture has now pushed data 
TestApp got data: 3 
Press any key to continue...
```

So, what I do not understand is why the variable "m_test" get messed up in the second case. 
I would very much appreciate if anyone could shed a light on this.

/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code:

```
void Scanner::run()
{
    CaptureData capture_data(1234);
    auto t = std::async(std::launch::async, &CaptureData::get_data, capture_data);
    my_futures.push_back(std::move(t));
```

}

`capture_data` is a local variable that goes out of scope and gets destroyed when the function returns. If you pass a pointer to that variable into `async` that pointer becomes a dangling pointer causing undefined behaviour. That does not happen if you pass it by value, as you do in the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a pointer to a stack allocated object. This object is destructed at the end of the `Scanner::run()` method. Thus, the pointer is now pointing to invalid memory when the async function runs.

The first method works, because the `capture_data` variable is move constructed when it is passed to the function, therefore it still retains it's structure.

I recommend using lambda functions than passing the raw member function:

```
void Scanner::run()
{
    CaptureData capture_data(1234);
    auto t = std::async(std::launch::async, [capture=std::move(capture_data)]() { capture.get_data(); });
    my_futures.emplace_back(t);
}
```

Even better is to construct the object inside the lambda function:

```
void Scanner::run()
{
    auto t = std::async(std::launch::async, []() { 
        CaptureData capture_data(1234);
        capture_data.get_data();
    });
    my_futures.emplace_back(t);
}
```

Comment: Why is using lambda functions better?

Comment: @Mats, it gives you more control over how to handle references and stuff. You can capture objects outside the scope of the function you want to call, using reference, value, or move. You can clearly see that in the first example I have, the object is captured by move, whereas it is not obvious that the move is happening in the code you had. Also it is not obvious that the member function is being called with `capture_data` as the object reference (`this`). Lambdas give you more expressiveness